# C++ SFML - How to read two keys in SFML pressed at the same time?

Tags: c++, keyboard, sfml

I made a very simple two player game in which one person is the jellyfish, and the other is the shark in SFML. The only problem with it is that only one sprite can move at once. Is this possible to fix and how can I fix it?

EDIT: My attempt is this:

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                bool D;
                bool A;
                bool S;
                bool W;
                bool Up;
                bool Right;
                bool Left;
                bool Down;
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                    A = true;



                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                     D = true;

                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::W)
                     W = true;

                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S)
                     S = true;

                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                     Left = true;

                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                     Right = true;

                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                     Up = true;

                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down)
                     Down = true;

                if (D and Right)
                {
                    jelly.move(10, 0)
                }
                  ...



            }
```

Comment: Of course you can fix that. You just need to keep track of what keys are pressed and what sprites to move when certain keys are pressed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But how can I keep track of two keys being pressed at the same time?

Comment: Use a couple of `bool` variables that you set to `true` when the relevant key is pressed and `false` when it is released - then test your bools to determine what to do.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How do I check if it is released?

Comment: SFML delivers you events both when keys are pressed and when they are released. Check the documentation. It's all described in great detail. Relevant link: http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/structsf_1_1Event_1_1KeyEvent.php

Comment: @JesperJuhl Alright, look at my edit. Where do I go from here?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I need to be able to have 2 at once but also only one.

Comment: Yes. I *get* that. If you have two `bool`s "key_a_pressed" and "key_b_pressed" that you keep updated based on events received, then you can simply do `if (key_a_pressed && key_b_pressed) { /* stuff to do when both pressed */ } else if (key_a_pressed) { /* stuff to do when only "a" pressed */ } else if (key_b_pressed) { /* stuff to do when only "b" pressed */ } else { /* stuff to do when none pressed */ } /* stuff to always do here */` ... It's not that hard.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your welcome. I hope you solved your problem.   Btw, this is exactly what @Joachim Pileborg said in his answer - I just spelled it out a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solve it by having a flag that is set when one key is pressed, and cleared when the key is released. Then you can check this flag when the other key is pressed.

Comment: The problem I have then is that when I press one key alone, it won't move. I want it to be able to handle two, and to be able to handle one.

Comment: @JamesBond You can use the flag for that too. In your main rendering/event loop, if the flag for the key is set (i.e it is being pressed) then update the position of whatever objects needs to be "moved". Do this before the rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use [`sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#a80a04b2f53005886957f49eee3531599) to probe the state of the keyboard at a given point.

One issue with your current code is that all the variables are local to the if-statement and therefore reinitialised when processing the next event. They should be defined outside the `if`. Another problem is that you don't handle the `KeyReleased` event.

Comment: The problem there is that mixing events and direct checks may result in conflicting results. Sure, you *can* probe the keys "right now", but that will miss "user pressed the key for a short amount of time and then released it" since it is not pressed *right now*. You usually want to pick being either driven by events or immediate results, but mixing them usually leads to confusion.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, hence the 'alternatively' ;)